# Save Json in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables

I'm studying javascript these days and I have question. I have variable that contain an url. I would like to save the content of the url pointed by my variable in another variable...

The first variable is something like:

```
var Link = "http://mysite.com/json/public/search?q=variabile&k=&e=1";
```

If I open the link I see something like:

```
{

"count": 1,
"e": 1,
"k": null,
"privateresult": 0,
"q": "gabriel",
"start": 0,
"cards": [
    {
        "__guid__": "cdf8ee96538c3811a6a118c72365a9ec",
        "company": false,
        "__title__": "Gabriel Butoeru",
        "__class__": "entity",
        "services": false,
        "__own__": false,
        "vanity_urls": [
            "gabriel-butoeru"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How can I save the json content in another javascript variable?

Comment: You can't unless the server you are accessing supports JSONP

Comment: Use AJAX to request it, then `JSON.parse` http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: the var Link is javascript variable! :S

Comment: @JellyBelly 
Captain obvious strikes again :D

Comment: I don't want to open the json file ... the content should be saved in the javascript variable. The code is just an example.

Comment: Same origin means you cannot read the contents. It is supposed to be loaded into the head of your page and executed in the scope of your site. You can read it on the server using a proxy or in php get_file_contents

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would need a simple AJAX request to get the contents into a variable.

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", yourUrl, false);
xhReq.send(null);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
```

Please note that AJAX is bound by [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), in case that URL is different this will fail.

Comment: Likely not from the same server.

Comment: since this is a very old post, just wanted to check if there is any new better approach for it? Mainly because I saw this warning when i tried the approach " Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this

```
  var savings_data = JSON.stringify(your_json_object);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can save json as object in this way**

Reference : [Json](http://www.json.org/js.html)

```
var obj = {};

 obj.name = "test";
 obj.no   = "1234";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you, using jQuery... :)

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() { DO HERE WHATEVER }, //Show spinner

            complete: function() { DO HERE WHATEVER  }, //Hide spinner

            type: 'POST',
            url: Link,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                                var data = data;
                               OR IF YOU WANT SEPARATE THE VALUES...
                                var count = data.count;
                                var e = data.e;
                                var k = data.k;
                                ...
             }                               
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

This example considers the state of the request and will allow you to access the data from the JSON format using the dot operator.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "mysite.com/json/public/search?q=variabile&k=&e=1", true); 
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 
request.send(); 
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(request.ready == 4 && request.readyState == 200){
          var response = request.responseText; 
          var obj = JSON.parse(response);
          alert(obj.count); // should return the value of count (i.e Count = 1) 
          alert(obj.e); // should return the value of e (i.e. e = 1) 
          var count = obj.count;  //store the result of count into your variable
          var e = obj.e; //store the result of e into your variable
          //...and so on 
     }
}
```